# Unreal Engine 5 assertion failed - world partition

Tags: unreal-engine5

When you start unreal engine 5 EA project with scene which using world partition show the error like this "Assertion failed: !StreamingPolicy [File:D:/build/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/WorldPartition/WorldPartition.cpp] [Line: 305]"

Answer (score 2):

For fix it you need open your project path and open Config\DefaultEngine.ini and set "EditorStartupMap = "
if it doesnt help change "GameDefaultMap = " too